# rails app - mongoid does not insert a new field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, model, mongoid

I just started to create on app with rails-api and mongoDB (gem mongoid in rails).

I have created my model like this:

```
class User 
    include Mongoid::Document
    include Mongoid::Timestamps

    embeds_many :language
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :language

    field :name, type: String
    field :lastname, type: String
    field :mail, type: String
    field :passwd, type: String
    field :auth_token, type: String
end
```

And i want to add another field in my model.

So at the end of my model i add this:

```
field :slug, type: String
```

But when i insert a new document, mongoid doesn't detect the new field and return null.

I try to do rake:migration but is useless with mongodb and i can't find the issue. Could you help me?

Best regards

Comment: You could also add a default to your new field, which would give all your old records a fallback value. `field :slug, type: String, :default => ""`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably you did not add that new field into your strong params whitelist.

Look into your controller and find a line that looks like this:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:name, ...)
```

Add `slug` there like this:

```
params.require(:user).permit(:name, ..., :slug)
```

Comment: It works !! I hate myself...  thanks for your help !

Comment: After updating the model and controller, my change was still not appearing. I had both rails console and the rails app running. Only after I restarted both did I see the change appear as expected FYI.

Comment: @Stephen I guess you are running your app in production mode. In development mode rails reloads changed classes.